# Validation fails on ":on => :save"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.0.10 and ruby 1.9.2p0

In my rails app I am trying to validate my model through a "validates_uniqueness_of"

In my model(label) there is field named as "name" and I want to validate it as:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:portal_id], :on => :save
```

Portal is another model in my app.

It validates perfectly when i use `:on => :create` or `:update` individually, but fails when i use `:on => :save`

any idea I want to validate on save, but AR validation fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As default all validations run before save.so no need to give :on => :save

Simply use

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:portal_id]
```

Comment: thanks soundar for your response.I know it is need less to pass :on => :save but in ActiveModel doc says if user :save at :on validation should work for create and update but it fails in these scenario just try it.